# HTML to PDF creation in AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, html-to-pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file that contains images, tables from HTML data in AWS lambda using python. I searched a lot on google and I didn't find any super cool solution. I tried some libraries in local(FPDF, pdfKit) and but it doesn't work on AWS. Is there any simple tool to create pdf and upload it to S3 bucket. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use reportlab PDF python module. It is good for all the things you have asked for. You can add images, create tables etc. There are a lot of styling options available as well. You can find more about it here: https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

I am using this is in my production and works pretty well for my use case where I have to create an invoice. You can create the invoice in the /tmp directory and then upload this to S3

Comment: Where I can set the path? If you don't mind please provide little more details.

Comment: You can not see the /tmp directory. It is just a temporary storage that is available at the time of lambda run time. One can use this for storing temporary files that may be created during the lambda execution. You can find more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

If you need further help, please let me know :)

Comment: Am confused with s3_object.put_object(). What is the value I need to pass on the key and body?  
    c = canvas.Canvas(sFilePath)
    c.drawString(100, 100, "Test Working!")
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
s3_object.put_objefct(key=filepath, body=?)

Comment: 'Key' will basically be the name of the file of the file you are trying to create in S3 bucket. For ex: temp.pdf. 

Now for the 'Body', you need to actually pass the content of the file if you are using the client.put_object() method. I would suggest you to first create a temporary file in the lambda env using the /tmp directory, call it temp_file.pdf and then use the client.upload_file() method to upload this temp_file.pdf to S3. You can find more about upload_file method here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Answer (score 1):

pdfkit library works with aws lambda. pdfkit internally needs the wkhtmltopdf binaries installed, you can add them as lambda layer. You can download files from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.

Once you add the lambda layers you can set the config path as following:

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf")

pdfkit.from_string/from_file(input, <temp path of pdf file on lambda>, configuration=config)
```

You can uplod the file generated in your lambda temp location to S3 bucket using upload_file(). You can refer https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file on how to upload to s3 bucket.